# Will an external monitor on a D7500 display what is shown in the live view?

Tags: live-view, rear-lcd, nikon-d7500

Will an external monitor on a Nikon D7500 allow me to see what is shown in the camera's live view window? I'm trying to find a way to get a larger view of what is shown on the camera LCD so it will be easier to see if the scene is in focus before taking the picture.

It  would be nice if I could see a larger view so I can see the camera's shutter speed, ISO, aperture, and focus appearance that are shown in the cameras small LCD display during Liveview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if connected via HDMI and enabled in the menu: Setup > HDMI > Advanced > Live view on-screen display > On

Answer (score 1):

The HDMI output on the D7000 closely mimics the live view display on the camera, minus a few minor items. All the important annunciators are displayed.